# incrementar campo com lambda

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Preciso inserir um incremento em um campo que é chave primária de uma tabela, porem preciso que seja feito um select por mais um campo e nao funciona, se uso apenas com a Chave primaria funciona. Mas preciso passar o outro parametro tambem.

```
    public string INSERT_EMBALAGEM(int EMP_ID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var bancodados = new takeeatEntities2())
            {
                //essa linha funciona 
                long maxes = bancodados.embalagens_80.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(x => x == null ? 1 : x.EML_ID_80 + 1);

                //Essa outra linha é a que eu preciso e não funciona, ela contem um parametro para ser o select da tabela
                long maxes = bancodados.embalagens_80.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(x => x == null ? 1 : x.EML_ID_80 + 1 && x.EMP_ID_80 == EMP_ID);

                embalagens_80 emb = new embalagens_80();
                emb.EML_ID_80 = maxes;
                emb.EMP_ID_80 = EMP_ID;

                bancodados.embalagens_80.Add(emb);
                bancodados.SaveChanges();

                return maxes.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução:**

```
 long maxes = bancodados.embalagens_80.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      .Where(x=>x==null||x.EMP_ID_80 == EMP_ID)
                                      .Max(x => x == null ? 1 : x.EML_ID_80 + 1) ;
```

No código acima estou selecionando todos os registro que são nulos ou que se não for nulo que o atributo EMP_ID_80 seja igual ao EMP_ID e depois estou pegando o máximo.

**Por que?**

No seu código você estava pegando um numero e tentando filtrar, Técnicamente você estava fazendo isso:

> ```
> .Max(x=>1 && x.EMP_ID_80 == EMP_ID)
> ```
>
> que é igual a
>
> ```
> if( 1 && EMP_ID_80 == EMP_ID)
> ```
>
> O que causa um  um erro sintático

Comment: valeu amigão deu certo. muito obrigado